# Insulation R value vs. foil facing

Tags: insulation

Insulation R value only relates to conducted heat.  Foil-facing reflects heat, so it reduces heat transfer between inside and outside via another mechanism (stops radiant heat from becoming conductive heat).  Comparing foil-faced and non-foil-faced insulation of the same R value, the foil-faced will reduce total heat transfer more.

I'm in a situation where I may need to replace foil-faced insulation with another type that is not foil-faced.  I can match the R value, but would lose the foil's reduction in radiant heat transfer.  That would translate to more conductive heat, which could be offset by increasing the R value.

Is there a way to figure out what increase in R value would yield equivalent reduction in heat transfer as the foil adds (i.e., maintain the same temperature difference between inside and outside as the foil-faced insulation)?

Comment: It will be a change in the radiant heat transfer, not conducted heat if the only change is a lack of foil... A good book about heat transfer is By Simonson.

Comment: @SolarMike, my understanding is that radiant heat gets reflected or absorbed.  If it's absorbed, it get converted to conductive heat.

Comment: This might be a question that better fits in Engineering. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ack, if this was a theoretical question, Engineering might be a better site to figure it out.  But I'm hoping this has already been figured out and there are existing, practical solutions ready to be applied by contractors and DIYers.

Answer (score 1):

The layer fields on the professional [Ubakus-Site](https://www.ubakus.de/u-wert-rechner/?) allows to input also metal foils, so it should take the reflections into account.
But those reflections do only have a tiny effect if the subject is building insulation. Much more important is the fact that metal is a barrier for waterdamp.
And in general, wet insulation material decreases the insulation effect. So in reality, removing a metal foil could improve the insulation.

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not have any association with that web site, I do not benefit/profit in any way from my recommendation of that site. It is just by far the most professional and sophisticated site to calculate and visualize the relevant insulation parameters that I have found up to now. For DIY the free access seems to be ideal. But I can't tell anything about the commercial option since I do not have access to it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That web site was a challenge--so much is in German (even with the English setting), and is based on the European model (U vs. R values).  It mentions radiant heat but didn't seem to factor it in (or I couldn't figure it out).  That said, I suspect you're right that the foil doesn't add much in my case.  It's in a basement, so radiant heat probably isn't a big factor.

Comment: I did not check all input fields, but the most important seemed to be translated. Switching to R instead U value is done by clicking on the tool symbol next to the U value. If radiant heat is not taken into account for metal layers, I assume it does not play a role in buildings - only it does as water damp barrier.